# Tag badge system bug?

Tags: support, badges

Now that we are discussing badges...

Seems like there might be a bug in the tag badge awarding system. If you look at my [profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1102) and see the number of votes for the [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral) tag, it seems like there must be a tag badge corresponding to that, but that does not seem to be present in the list of badges.

Comment: Can I downvote my own question? It shows a complete lack of reasearch! Apologies...

Comment: I can do it for you if you want :-P

Comment: @Asaf: ..... :-)

Comment: Why are people voting to close this?  I was about to ask a similar question once, but I found this one and found the answer I was looking for here.  It's not too localized.  Just because a specific question is asked doesn't mean the general principles are not helpful?  Is asking to find a specific integral too localized because only people wanting to know how to do that specific integral will ever use it?  No, because others will use it who have similar problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think at least one of your 20 answers is CW, and I don't think CW answers count toward the minimum-of-20-answers requirement.

Comment: I didn't know there was a minimum answer requirement! What is the logic for that? "Minimum" contribution?

Comment: It is an arbitrary threshold set, just like the 100 upvotes for a tag. I mean, why should there even *be* tag badges?

Comment: @Willie: Because it is so cool.

Comment: @Willie: The point of badges is to encourage participation and in that sense, having to cross 20 answers before you get it makes sense, I suppose.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I think the idea is something along the lines of preventing people from getting the tag badges by having one wildly popular answer.  That is, it means you have to contribute a volume of answers that get upvoted rather than just an answer or two to some very popular questions.

Comment: @Isaac: Yeah, I guess that makes sense too :-)